# Orchard export/import

Tags: xslt, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7, orchardcms-1.8

I have created a custom module to manage a list of data I have.

The idea was to export the structure, transform my original data and import them in my module.

So far, so good (I did previously with other data)

The problem is that I have an attached image.

The name is easy to attach (as it is the same of an unique id I have) but Orchard instead of exporting image by name it exports using an unique id...

```
<MediaLibraryPickerField.Immagine ContentItems="/Identifier=c4e47c4a25554f99a399ce54b4549ae0" />
```

So how I can XSL transform something like

```
<Image>4567.jpg</Image>
```

to an unknown id?

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround.

If image does not exist I can import image as well as part of import process.

The important thing is to assign an unique id to imported image and use the same id con image field.

This way it works.